# Blender automatically unassigning vertex groups

Tags: rigging, vertex-groups

I have been learning blender for a while but I can't solve one problem, I created a human model using manuel bastioni add-on I then duplicated the torso and legs to create clothes, However when I close blender and reopen it automatically removes the clothes I created from their vertex groups. The origional mesh is still bound to the armature and any other mesh I try to add to any vertex group gets automatically removed when I close blender. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Do you save before closing? Are clothes animated and you try to save file on some frame? What does it mean "clothes I created from their vertex groups"?

Comment: I make other small changes to ensure that it saves, I have not animated anything yet, and when I create clothes and assign them to vertex groups to bind it to the armature then I close blender and reopen it and the clothes are no longer assigned to any vertex groups.